# does numberformatexception catch nullpointerexception?

Tags: exception

does try catch of NumberFormatException could handle NullPointerException? and does try catch of Exception could handle any type of exception?

```
try {

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 try {

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Any sub-class of Exception you can see there is going to be catched by the try catch Exception.

NumberFormatException and NullpointerException are also Exception, but they're neither a sub-class of each other. That is, the first try-catch you stated won't catch a NullPointerException and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax doesn't make sense, you can catch multiple exceptions, the most specific/narrow class of exception higher on the list:

```
try {
     ..code here...

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```